# Commands like "ls -l" not executing in execl, whereas in execvp it works

Tags: c, exec

Using the code below in the `execl` variant, `ls` works, but `ls -l` does not work, but in my `execvp` approach `ls` and `ls-l` works. The reason why I adopted the `execl` approach is because the path of the binaries could differ whereas `execvp` did not provide me that feature. Ideally I want `execl` to also work on `ls -l`, but right now it does not work on `ls -l`. I tried reading the man pages but it did not help.

```
void child(int argc, char *argv[MAX_ARGS])
{
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
}


void child(char *argv[], char* path)
{
        execl(path, argv, NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `execl()`, you have to list the arguments one by one; it is only useful if you know exactly what you're going to execute ahead of time:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char *)0);
execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "ls -l", (char *)0);
execl("/bin/ls", "pink elephants", "-l", (char *)0);
```

Etc.

If you don't know how many arguments you'll have to deal with, use `execvp()` or one of the other members of the `execv*()` family.  Also note that you have to specify the path of the command; `execvp()` does a search down `$PATH`, but `execl()` does not.
Also note that you get to choose the value passed as `argv[0]`.

> The reason why I adopted the `execl()` approach is because the path of the binaries could differ whereas `execvp()` did not provide me that feature.

I'm not sure what you mean here.  With `execvp()`, you can specify:

```
char *argv[] = { "ls", "-l", 0 };
execvp(argv[0], argv);
execv("/bin/ls", argv);
```

The `execvp()` will search for `ls` on `$PATH` and execute the first program found that matches.  The second will execute `/bin/ls` without looking at `$PATH` at all.

```
char *argv[] = { "/bin/ls", "-l", 0 };

execv(argv[0], argv);
execvp(argv[0], argv);
```

Either of these will work; the second won't use a PATH-based search because the executable name (`argv[0]`) contains a slash.

---

> What confuses me is that in `execvp(argv[0], argv);` why are we passing the entire `argv` as the 2nd parameter? So suppose `argv[0]` was `"ls -l"`, why do we have to pass the entire `argv` as the 2nd parameter?

Supposing `argv[0]` contains `"ls -l"`, you have a problem.  Most systems do not have a file "`/bin/ls -l`" or "`/usr/bin/ls -l`" (where the blank is part of the name), but that's what you'd be seeking to execute.

The `exec*()` functions are the low-level functions for executing processes.  The first argument designates the program to be run (normally, a binary; sometimes a script with a shebang line such as `#!/bin/sh` as the first line).  In the case of `execv()` or `execvp()` or `execve()` or `execvpe()`, the second argument is the vector of arguments, just like the `main()` function receives a vector of arguments (or argument vector, hence `argv`).  This is a null-terminated list of the arguments to the program.  If you want to execute the `ls` command with the option `-l`, then you need to specify in the `argv` the three(!) values `"ls"`, `"-l"` and a null pointer:

```
char argv[] = { "ls", "-l", 0 };
```

With the `execl*()` functions, you specify the program to be run as the first argument, and this is then followed by the argument vector written out:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char *)0);
```

If you have 10 arguments, you have to write out 10 arguments (plus the null pointer).

In the `exec*()` functions, the names contain:

- `l` — list format arguments
- `v` — vector format arguments
- `p` — do PATH lookup on the program (if the given name does not contain a slash)
- `e` — take a vector of environment variables too

These combine to give:

- `execl()`
- `execv()`
- `execlp()`
- `execle()`
- `execvp()`
- `execve()`

It is occasionally a tad irksome that there isn't an `execlpe()` and `execvpe()` (but see the Linux extension [`execvpe(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvpe.3.html)).  It is also traditional for the `man 2 exec` pages to omit some of these from the synopsis but mention them in the body of the manual page — a tradition/legacy dating back to at least 7th Edition UNIX™ in 1979 (and perpetuated at least until RHEL 5 Linux and Mac OS X 10.7.5; the `man 2 execl` page mentions `execve()` but does not list it in the Synopsis section).  The other `exec*()` functions can all be built atop `execve()` — that is the fundamental function in the set (and is listed as [`execve(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) in the Linux manuals as a result).

Comment: What confuses me is that in execvp(argv[0], argv); why are we passing the entire argv as the 2nd parameter? So suppose argv[0] was ls -l, why do we have to pass the entire argv as the 2nd paramter? I tried studying the man page but it still didn't make sense to me

Comment: If `argv[0]` was `"ls -l"`, you'd get an error because there is no program called `ls -l`.